# Call REST Webservice using DB2 from COBOL batch using HTTP session

Tags: db2, restful-authentication, cobol

Is it possible to call a RESTful web service that uses basic authentication using COBOL to make a call to DB2?  The username/password are not passed in the URL, but are captured in the HTTP session to provide authentication.

Using something like

```
>  http://username:password@myhost
```

does not work.  I've created clients in Java and modded the proxy to pass the username/password in the HTTP session, but not sure if this can be done via DB2 called from COBOL batch.

```
               EXEC SQL
               SELECT RETURNCODE, RETURNMSG
               INTO :SIMR-RETURNCODE, :SIMR-RETURNMSG
               FROM XMLTABLE(
               '$d/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:myWebServiceResponse/*:messageResponse'
               PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT
                DB2XML.SOAPHTTPNV(VARCHAR (:WS-URL),
               VARCHAR (:BEACTION),
               VARCHAR (:BEXML))
                ) AS "d"
               COLUMNS
               "RETURNCODE" VARCHAR(4) PATH '*:returnCode',
               "RETURNMSG" VARCHAR(156) PATH '*:returnMessage'
               ) AS T
               END-EXEC

:WS-URL = http://username:password@host/webservice
```

Is there a way to set the username/password that will be made in the HTTP session call?  The webservice I'm calling uses basic auth to validate against AD/LDAP.